# Spring authorization server, how do I set scope for each grant type

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I want to make a custom grant_type 'mfa'. let's say a user want to gain access token they have to get access token with scope 'mfa_required' first.

```
    RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("cheems_doge")
            .clientSecret("very_secret_wow")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc")
            .scope("mfa_required") // so this token will be able to use with mfa grant_type only.
            .clientSettings(
                    ClientSettings.builder() // remove consent page.
                    .requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                    .requireProofKey(true)
                    .build())
            .build();
```

and then they will use this access token to gain another access token with grant_type mfa.

```
RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("cheems_doge_2")
                .clientSecret("very_secret_wow_2")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_JWT)
                .authorizationGrantType(CustomGrantType.MFA)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc")
                .scope("write read etc..") // this token will be able to access resource server.
                .clientSettings(
                        ClientSettings.builder()
                                .requireAuthorizationConsent(true)
                                .requireProofKey(false)
                                .build())
                .build();
```

but I cant create RegisteredClient with difference scope for each grant_type. I have to create a new RegisteredClient so the client have to store 2 client_id one for the first token and another one for mfa. Is there a way to set difference scope for each grant_type.